# The data is not reloaded after button click in Blazor App

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I have a list with keyissues.

1.When a key is returned, the user will click on a button.

2. When the button is clicked, the page have to redirect to the same page, but the button have to change to a text which says that the key is returned.
3. I have to tables: KeysList(the list of all avalible keys with a status: Bool IsReturned.
   The second table is KeyIssues with a status: Bool Isreturned.

problem 1: It seems that the status of the table KeyIssues is not always have been updated. The other table is alweay up to date after clicking the button.

Problem 2:
When the user clicks the button, the same page (dashboard) have to reload,and the status of the data has to update, this does not work. I have to go to another page before i see the result.

I could not find the problem. Could you please tell me what is wrong with the function?

The dashboard page

```
    @*Key issues*@
    <div class="card mb-4 shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
        <div class="card-header text-center text-warning bg-white border-warning">
            <h4 class="">Laatste 5 sleuteluitgite</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <h4 class="">Datum</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <h4>Aan</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <h4>Sleutel</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <h4>Retour</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        @foreach (var item in keyIssues)
        {
            if (item == null)
            {
                <p>Loading..</p>
            }
            else
            {
                var SelectedId = @keysList.Where(m => m.Id.ToString() == item.KeyId).Select(m => m.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        @item.DateAdded.ToShortDateString()
                    </div>
                    @if (item.IssuedTo != null)
                    {
                        <div class="col">
                            @UserList.Where(m=>m.Id.ToString() == @item.IssuedTo).Select(m=>m.FirstName + " " + m.LastName).FirstOrDefault()
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            @keysList.Where(m=>m.Id.ToString() == item.KeyId).Select(m=>m.KeyNumber + " " + m.KeyName).FirstOrDefault()
                        </div>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <div class="col">
                            @item.FirstName @item.LastName
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            @keysList.Where(m=>m.Id.ToString() == item.KeyId).Select(m=>m.KeyNumber + " " + m.KeyName).FirstOrDefault()
                        </div>
                    }
                  
                    @if (item.IsReturned == false)
                    {
                        <div class="col mb-2">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" id="@item.Id" @onclick=" () => SetItemInactive(SelectedId)">Inleveren</button>
                        </div>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <div class="col">
                            <p class="text-success">Retour</p>
                        </div>
                    }
                    <hr>
                </div>
            }
        }
    </div>

    async Task SetItemInactive(string id)
    {
        var item = keysList.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);
        if (item != null)
        {
            if (KeyService != null)
            {
                await KeyService.SetItemInActive(item.Id);
            }
            StateHasChanged();
            if (item.IsReturned == true)
            {
                NavManager.NavigateTo("/");
            }

         
          
        }

    }
```

The IndexBase of the dasboard

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Univi.Client.Services.Interface;
using Univi.Server.Models;
using Univi.Shared;


namespace Univi.Client.Pages.Dashboard
{

    public partial class IndexBase : ComponentBase
    {
        [Inject]
        protected IReportService? ReportService { get; set; }
        [Inject] 
       protected IKeyService? KeyService { get; set; }
        [Inject]
        protected IKindofReportService? KindofReportService { get; set; }
        [Inject]
        protected IBuildingService? BuildingService { get; set; }
        [Inject]
       protected  IHandoverService? HandoverService { get; set; }
        [Inject]
        protected IMalfunctionService? MalfunctionService { get; set; }
        [Inject]
        protected IUserService? UserService { get; set; }

        protected List<Report> ReportsList = new();
        protected List<KeyIssue> keyIssues = new();
        protected List<KeyList> keysList = new();
        protected List<Building> buildings = new();
        protected List<Kindofreport> kindofReports = new();
        protected List<Handover> handoverslist = new();
        protected List<Malfunction> malfunctionList = new();
        protected List<StatusCode> StatuscodeList = new();
        protected List<KindofMalfunction> KindofMalfunctionList = new();
        protected List<User>UserList = new();


        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            if(HandoverService != null)
            {
                handoverslist = await HandoverService.GetHandovers();
            }

            if(ReportService != null)
            {
                ReportsList = await ReportService.GetLast5Reports();

            }
            if (KeyService != null)
            {
                keyIssues = await KeyService.GetKeyIssuesAsync();
                keysList = await KeyService.GetKeyListAsync();
            }
            if(BuildingService != null)
            {
                buildings = await BuildingService.GetBuildingsAsync();
            }
            if (KindofReportService != null)
            {
                kindofReports = await KindofReportService.GetKindsOfReportAsync();
            }
            if(MalfunctionService != null)
            {
                malfunctionList = await MalfunctionService.GetMalfunctionsAsync();
                StatuscodeList = await MalfunctionService.GetStatusCodesAsync();
            }
            if(UserService != null)
            {
                UserList = await UserService.GetUsersAsync();
            }


        }

    }
}
```

The controller which is responsible for changing and update the satus

```
        [HttpPost("inactive")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SetItemInactive([FromBody] string id)
        {
            //Find the current key and set IsReturned to TRUE
            var item = await _context.KeysList.FindAsync(id);
           
            if (item != null)
            {
                var issue = _context.KeyIssues.Where(m => m.KeyId == id).FirstOrDefault();
                if (issue != null)
                {
                     item.IsReturned = true;
                     issue.IsReturned = true;
                    if (issue.IsReturned == true && item.IsReturned == true)
                    {
                        _context.KeyIssues.Update(issue);
                        _context.KeysList.Update(item);
                        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                        return Ok(item);
                    }            
                }
   
            }

            return NoContent();
        }
```

Comment: Navigating to the same page you are leaving will only trigger a `OnParametersSetAsync`.  You aren't loading a new component, just potentially changing some parameters.  If you place your loading code in `OnParametersSetAsync` you need to manually detect those changes to decide if you need to reload your data.  Doing it on every `OnParametersSetAsync` could get expensive.  The normal practice would be as @HH suggests to reload whatever data you need to after making the change.  `SetItemInActive` is a UI event so will trigger a render event when it completes.